# Woocommerce pagination adding an anchor point

Tags: php, wordpress

When clicking on a pagination button < 12345 > in woocommerce product section it keeps jumping to the top of the page and the user has to scroll down to the products again to get to the next page of products.

This is my code that I'm trying to get working it adds #catgories to the pagination link but doesn't jump to the anchor any ideas guys?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_pagination_args' , 'tq73et_override_pagination_args' );
function tq73et_override_pagination_args( $args ) {
    $args['add_fragment'] = __( '#categories' );
    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery to scroll or javascript. You can find alot of examples on stackoverflow.

I will use jQuery for the example. If you dont have jQuery on your website you have to load it first - https://code.jquery.com/ . You can upload it to your website if you want or use cdn link.

So we want to animate scrolling trought our page so we need to get the html and body and start scrolling down until we reach element with id categories with 1000ms speed. You can change the speed as lower is faster, higher is slower.

```
$(function() { 
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#categories').offset().top}, 1000);
})(jQuery);
```

Another example - https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

Comment: Is there a way to incorporate this into woocommerce pagination after the page reload? Im guessing this will be everytime the page loads